# Blender script import model and render it

Tags: python, scripting, import

I know python well, but I'm not familiar with blender.

Is it possible to use the blender API to do this?

Setup:  Create a scene in which the the lights and cameras are pre-arranged.

Run a python script which:

1. Imports a model (fbx or obj).
2. Renders from each camera and saves output to a .png file.
3. Returns to step 1 until all models have been rendered.

Comment: You can take a look at this addon.
https://www.blendermarket.com/products/image-batch-automation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's an outline with obj import, creates one camera in a new scene, loops thru a model list, makes a new scene with links to cam in created scene, loops thru the cams in the new scene (add more) and renders.  You will need to edit the paths to suit your needs:

```
import bpy
import os
from math import radians

context = bpy.context

models_path = "//"
render_path = "//"

models = ["bretling.obj", "bretling.obj"]

#create a scene
scene = bpy.data.scenes.new("Scene")
camera_data = bpy.data.cameras.new("Camera")

camera = bpy.data.objects.new("Camera", camera_data)
camera.location = (-2.0, 3.0, 3.0)
camera.rotation_euler = ([radians(a) for a in (422.0, 0.0, 149)])
scene.objects.link(camera)

# do the same for lights etc
scene.update()

for model_path in models:
    scene.camera = camera
    path = os.path.join(models_path, model_path)
    # make a new scene with cam and lights linked
    context.screen.scene = scene
    bpy.ops.scene.new(type='LINK_OBJECTS')
    context.scene.name = model_path
    cams = [c for c in context.scene.objects if c.type == 'CAMERA']
    #import model
    bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=path, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y', filter_glob="*.obj;*.mtl")
    for c in cams:
        context.scene.camera = c                                    
        print("Render ", model_path, context.scene.name, c.name)
        context.scene.render.filepath = "somepathmadeupfrommodelname"
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

The import operator code can be gleaned from the *Python Console* by typing in `bpy.ops.import` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> which will auto complete, for FBX:

```
>>> bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(
fbx()
bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath="", axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y', directory="", filter_glob="*.fbx", ui_tab='MAIN', use_manual_orientation=False, global_scale=1, bake_space_transform=False, use_custom_normals=True, use_image_search=True, use_alpha_decals=False, decal_offset=0, use_anim=True, anim_offset=1, use_custom_props=True, use_custom_props_enum_as_string=True, ignore_leaf_bones=False, force_connect_children=False, automatic_bone_orientation=False, primary_bone_axis='Y', secondary_bone_axis='X', use_prepost_rot=True)
```

As you mention you are o fay with python, this should be well enough to make you dangerous.

*Ideally I would probably set this up as an import operator with multi file select from a folder.*

Comment: Somehow irrelevant but would appreciate if you can give me some help on this: I am importing many .obj files sequentially. Very quickly, the import time increases significantly to the point that it takes minutes for each object (even the ones with low-complexity) to get imported. Could you please take a look at my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102333/why-importing-obj-files-becomes-extremely-slow) and see if you can offer a solution?

Comment: @Amir and others: Blender is horrible at importing/adding a huge number to the scene, because it includes running operations that get more complex the more objects already exist. Things like checking the uniqueness of the name are run, etc. It'd a trick to merge the newly added object with an existing one to keep the object count low.

Comment: AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'link'