# Python script to render a single .obj

Tags: python, scripting, light

I am familiar with python but completely new to Blender. I want to create a python script to read an obj file and render it from a fixed camera with a fixed lighting and save it to an image. Is there an introductory script that I can see?

My constraints are that I am on a remote server without an X connection, so I can't launch a GUI.

I ran into this question, but it doesn't tell me how to set up lighting:
[Blender script import model and render it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39303/blender-script-import-model-and-render-it)

Thanks!

Comment: As well as running a python script from the cli, you can start blender as a [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#python-options) and dynamically type in commands, benders modules don't get auto imported this way so you still need to import bpy to get started.

Answer (score 2):

Blender's object oriented approach uses a generic object for items in a scene with a varied data block that varies for each type of object. Using python we can create the [lamp data](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Lamp.html) and use it when [adding an object](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html) to the scene, which can then be positioned where you want it. You could add a sun lamp and rotate it as desired, or if you wanted a spot light you could use a trackto constraint to point it at the object.

```
import bpy
from math import radians

# sun lamp
light_data = bpy.data.lamps.new('sun', 'SUN')
light_obj = bpy.data.objects.new('sun', light_data)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(light_obj)

light_obj.location = (2.0,2.0,2.0)
light_obj.rotation_euler = (radians(10), radians(15), radians(20))

# spotlight
light_data = bpy.data.lamps.new('light', 'SPOT')
light_obj = bpy.data.objects.new('light', light_data)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(light_obj)

light_obj.location = (2.0,2.0,2.0)
light_constr = light_obj.constraints.new('TRACK_TO')

light_constr.target = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
light_constr.track_axis = 'TRACK_NEGATIVE_Z'
light_constr.up_axis = 'UP_X'

light_data.spot_size = radians(25)
```

Comment: I am importing many `.obj` files sequentially. Very quickly, the import time increases significantly to the point that it takes minutes for each object (even the ones with low-complexity) to get imported. Could you please take a look at my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102333/importing-new-obj-files-becomes-extremely-slow-even-when-old-objects-are-remove) and see if you can offer a solution?  Appreciate it.