# Python: exchange object

Tags: python, objects

I got a .blend file where I got a simple cube and a plane. The Cube has some attributes like being a rigid body etc.

Now I let this cube fall on to the plane and then render an Image. This is my code:

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']

scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'
scene.render.filepath = '/path/testImage.png'
scene.render.resolution_x = 640
scene.render.resolution_y = 640

scene.frame_set(scene.frame_end)
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still = True)
```

I would like to exchange the cube-object with another object coming from an `.stl` file. So loading this stl object and having it instead of the cube but with the same attributes that I set to the cube and at the same position.

How can I do this?

Comment: After the import the newly imported object(s) are `context.selected_objects` one of which is `context.object`  Making `obj.data = context.object.data` after import will give cube above mesh of imported object.  It will naff materials tho.

Comment: @batFINGER I don't care about the materials so this would be fine. How do I import it?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127883/import-stl-and-render-image

Comment: Thanks! It kind of works now. But my problem is, that on my rendered Image I can't see anything. I guess the size of my stl-file object is much bigger then the one from the cube. Is there a possibility to scale it to the same size?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160976/how-can-i-normalize-the-scale-of-what-seems-to-be-either-an-infinitely-large-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from @batFinger I derived this working solution:

```
import bpy
import os

scene = bpy.context.scene
cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']

scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'
scene.render.filepath = 'testImage.png'
scene.render.resolution_x = 640
scene.render.resolution_y = 640

# change mesh
path = r"assembly_upsampled.stl"
bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=path)
obj.data = bpy.context.object.data
bpy.data.objects.remove(bpy.context.object)

# scale size
max_dim = 2
if obj.dimensions.length:
    obj.scale *= max_dim / max(obj.dimensions)

# render
scene.frame_set(scene.frame_end)
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still = True)
```

Comment: For single mesh could remove meshobs and loop for `obj.scale *= max_dim / max(obj.dimensions)`   _still test it has dimension_

Comment: then loop over what?

Comment: Put that badly,.. no loop required its like `mesh_obs = [obj]`  So instead of looping simply `if obj.dimensions.length: (normalize dimension of obj)`

Comment: @batFINGER I edited the answer. Thank you so much for your help! One other question: Is it possible to delete the imported stl after copying the mesh, without deleting my cube and plane? I only know `bpy.ops.object.delete() `

Comment: @batFINGER Do you mean `bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)`? But how do I know the `obj`. `import_mesh` returns a set, right?

Comment: yes.  Already used to swap mesh, the imported object `ob = context.object` then `bpy.data.objects.remove(ob)`