# Make animations automatically using python?

Tags: python

I know you can use python code to place and move objects on the blender workspace. Is it possible to automate everything else?

I'm thinking about running a python script that places the objects, gives them their color and other properties, render it as an image from a certain point of view, then moving the objects just a little and render again and so on?

I want to make an animation of a magnetic field changing in time. This means, arrows pointing in many directions, each with a different length, filling a 3D space and changing in time. Programing the field itself is relatively easy but how can I make a video out of it?

Comment: Render as image sequence and then compile to mp4, mov or whatever using ffmpeg. Frequently asked question btw: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39303/blender-script-import-model-and-render-it or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130404/script-to-render-one-object-from-different-angles and there is more...

Comment: Since blender has many animation tools provided, recommend using python to create the animation data.