# creating a video of gif of showing different viewpoints of an .obj file

Tags: objects, 3d-view, video, motion-capture

I have opened an .obj file in blender and want to see its different view and create a video of it minus the black screen behind it. How can I do so in OSX?

[image]

Maybe another frame in video is:
[image]

Comment: So do you want to create a video or gif?

Comment: a gif would be best but video will be ok too.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39303/blender-script-import-model-and-render-it

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks for sharing the link. Can the script rotate this human automatically and show various views without me setting up a new camera?

Comment: That specific script was written to make use of existing cameras. You could modify it to rotate an object or the camera itself.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in way to export as a gif, but you can get most of the way there.  Simply animate or setup your camera angle, and save the render as a JPG (or some other lossy image format).  I'm guessing you want an OpenGL-esque simple render, so switch the render engine to Workbench (that'll remove the overlays automatically).  Once you have your images, you can use ezgif.com or some other application to convert your image sequence into an animated gif.